# Queries in maven expression

Tags: maven-3

Is it possible to query maven for a specific plugin with `help:evaluate` goal ?
I know I can do `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.build.plugins` to get all plugins (in xml format), and `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.build.plugins[0]` to get the first plugin, but I don't succeed to query for a specific plugin.

My purpose is for example to get the configuration of the org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin just with help:evaluate goal, not with a combination of commands like grep, xmlstartlet, ...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?